# Selecting node where attribute matches node value in XSLT

Tags: xslt

The below returns 11 nodes:

```
//xs:schema/xs:element/xs:keyref
```

---

The below returns `Artist_FK_AlbumArtistId`:

```
ars:Relation/@Name
```

---

This returns one node:

```
//xs:schema/xs:element/xs:keyref[@name='Artist_FK_AlbumArtistId']
```

---

The below does however not return anything:

```
//xs:schema/xs:element/xs:keyref[@name=ars:Relation/@Name]
```

How can I use the value of `ars:Relation/@Name` to filter out the `xs:keyref` I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a key

```
<xsl:key name="ref-by-name" match="xs:element/xs:keyref" use="@name"/>
```

then you can use `key('ref-by-name', ars:Relation/@name)`.

Comment: To make it shorter yes but how do I add the `[@name=$relationName]`?

Comment: Access by key is more efficient. I don't understand your question about `[@name=$relationName]` as your original code does not use any variable reference `$relationName` and using a key certainly does not require you to use one. With the key defined as in my answer, the function call `key('ref-by-name', ars:Relation/@name)` is all you need to access the `xs:keyref` element(s) where the `name` attribute is equal to `ars:Relation/@name`.

Comment: I'll check it out and yes, there was no mention in my original question about relationName...

Answer (score 0):

I always manage to figure it out ten minutes after asking...

Here is how to do it:

```
<xsl:variable name="relationName" select="ars:Relation/@Name" />
<xsl:value-of select="//xs:schema/xs:element/xs:keyref[@name=$relationName]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

On its own

```
ars:Relation/@Name
```

is a path relative to whatever is the current node in the context where you execute the XPath.  But the same expression inside a predicate is relative to the node that the predicate is testing, i.e.

```
//xs:schema/xs:element/xs:keyref[@name=ars:Relation/@Name]
```

is looking for an `ars:Relation` element inside the `xs:keyref`.  But since you've tagged your question "xslt" you have access to the `current()` function, which provides access from inside the predicate to the current context node outside the whole expression:

```
//xs:schema/xs:element/xs:keyref[@name = current()/ars:Relation/@Name]
```

Comment: Am I not at `current()` for `ars:Relation/@Name` already or does it change scope when doing the match?

Comment: @Asken outside the `[]`, `current()` means the same as `.` - the context node for the current template/for-each. _Inside_ the brackets `current()` stays the same but `.` changes to refer to the node that the predicate is testing.